# Mapping subdomain to a virtual machine

Tags: networking, routing, virtual-machines, subdomain

I Have one dedicated server running Windows Server 2012 with one public IP.

This server is hosting a Linux virtual machine.

Is it possible to point example.com to the Windows host and route all traffic coming from vm.example.com to the Linux guest or do I need a failover IP to be able to do this ?

For now I'm mapping some ports (port 22 is one of them) from the windows host to the linux guest using `netsh interface portproxy` but I was wondering if it was possible to route all traffic depending on the subdomain, thus keeping all ports available on both machines.

For example ftp://example.com would point to the Windows ftp on port 21 and ftp://vm.example.com would point to the Linux ftp, also 21. All of this with one single public IP.

Note that I only have access to the dedicated server, no routers or anything else.

Is there a way to achieve this with or without third party program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt easily done, due to the way DNS works. When you request a website, the browser includes the domain, and this is why a single web server on a single IP can serve multiple sub domains.

It could be possible to have your Windows IIS server to act as a proxy to the linux machine, but this isn't very clean.

Edit: Sorry, I did not see FTP in the original question. No this isn't possible.

It might be worth asking your provider for an additional IP.

Comment: I'll accept this and stick with port mapping for the moment. I will just add that I knew it was easily doable for HTTP since the Host is included in the request's header. Unfortunately it's not the case for all protocols so it seems even software solutions couldn't achieve this kind of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

No, without an unique IP, there's no way to route that traffic like you want.  DNS is just a nice way of presenting the IP.